# Is it possible to exclude a script execution from manual reload (location.reload();)?

Tags: javascript, reload

Fairly basic question regarding `location.reload();`: is it possible to exclude the execution of a certain script (that is executed when the page is visited/loaded regularly) from the reload?

Comment: Can you change the script in question?

Comment: `location.reload()` will do exactly that, and there's no way to tell it to `location.reloadButSlightlyDifferent()`.  Explain the situation as there will be a better approach to your issue.

Comment: @CertainPerformance well, I´d have to be able to execute the script only on the initial visit of the page – is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right before `reload`, assign to a `sessionStorage` item. Then, in your other script, test to see if that `sessionStorage` item is populated. If it is populated, then this is not the initial visit; don't continue executing. Else, continue as normal. Eg:

```
function doReload() {
  sessionStorage.hasVisited = 'true';
  location.reload();
}
```

Other script that you want to conditionally execute:

```
if (!sessionStorage.hasVisited) {
  // execute body of script
}
```

`sessionStorage` will automatically clear on new sessions, which includes accessing the site from a new window. If you want something more permanent, use `localStorage`, which will persist until you clear it yourself.